# Why does $TERM var equal linux with virtual terminals

Tags: linux, terminal

Is there a terminal linux?  I was experimenting with the machine to see how the virtual terminals work and when I echo $TERM it printed linux? Is this the default linux terminal? I tried searching for man pages on linux but only results about the operating system return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `linux` terminal type is for the [virtual consoles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) (also called virtual terminals or consoles), the text-mode consoles provided by Linux on PC-style hardware and reached by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and so on. Like all modern terminal types, it's a variant on [VT100](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) and successors.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a terminal description identified by the name `linux`.

The `infocmp` program will show you the details of a given terminal identifier. On Debian-based systems, `infocmp` is in the `ncurses-bin` package.

```
$ infocmp linux
#       Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /lib/terminfo/l/linux
...
```

I've elided the escape codes for the capabilities. The man page for `terminfo(5)` describes all the capabilities and what they mean.

Answer (score 0):

The `TERM` environment variable identifies a terminal description.  The name `linux` has been used since its introduction in ncurses in [1994](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/c3aaabc43be8c42d70aa4588bff2034c3356c70c/data/linux) as the preferred name for Linux console (rather than `console`).

The ncurses terminal database defines more than a dozen variants, which some people use.  In the terminal database, `linux` is an alias for the version which most people are expected to use. Most people use the alias, for the usual reasons relating to terminal descriptions:

- while changing the alias is trivial (using infocmp and tic), most people don't modify their terminal database to point the alias to a different version,
- the name is used in the `getty` definitions (or equivalent), and again, most people don't change **that**, and of course
- some programs (such as GNU ls) have their own idea about how to manage the `linux` name (and do not bother to use the terminal database).

Expanding on that last item, the [initial version of GNU ls](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/src/dircolors.hin?id=0a3fdd250a63fca8a5bf1aa2df728f25b91990c8) in June 1996 used these names for values of `TERM` that supported color:

```
TERM linux
TERM console
TERM con132x25
TERM con132x30
TERM con132x43
TERM con132x60
TERM con80x25
TERM con80x28
TERM con80x30
TERM con80x43
TERM con80x50
TERM con80x60
TERM xterm
TERM vt100
```

using several "console" variants which were not ever provided by ncurses but apparently had some use.  That likely motivated the comment in ncurses' `INSTALL` (first seen in [September 1995](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/6be402a84b6ccffa07c6e3080fb714a83c6a057c/INSTALL#L192)):

```
In various systems there has been a practice of designating the system
console driver type as `console'.  Please do not do this!  It
complicates peoples' lives, because it can mean that several different
terminfo entries from different operating systems all logically want to
be called `console'.
```

Regardless of use, none of those were dropped, and (for Linux console), only `linux-c` was added (in [1999](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/src/dircolors.hin?id=e2e5b7324e2223c780e1b7b8383f56a793b383df), versus [1996](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-linux-c) in ncurses).  The [current file](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/dircolors.hin) has for instance

```
TERM con[0-9]*x[0-9]*
TERM linux
TERM linux-c
```

Further reading:

- [Origin of /etc/termcap linux entry](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259426/origin-of-etc-termcap-linux-entry)
- [How do I get color with VT100?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#vt100_color)